# How to fix vscode online integrated terminal issue

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

How do you fix this weird issue I have been having with vscode online?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vprpR.png

I tried resetting my vscode settings and updating it

Answer (score 0):

Are we talking about https://vscode.dev/ ?

In the settings try change the font.

Goto Settings (ctrl+,) > Text Editor > Fonts

Did a reboot work?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).